# How to make a function switch with numba

Tags: python, numba

I have 3 jitted functions, `a(x)`, `b(x)` and `c(x)`.

I need a switch function that does this:

```
@nb.njit
def switch(i, x):
    if i == 0:
        return a(x)
    elif i == 1:
        return b(x)
    elif i == 2:
        return c(c)
```

But I would like to write it in a more concise way without performance loss, such as:

```
functions = (a, b, c)

@nb.njit
def switch(i, x):
    functions[i](x)
```

However, nopython jit compilation can't handle tuples of functions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the functions share the same type signature it should be possible, see the example at:
https://numba.discourse.group/t/typed-list-of-jitted-functions-in-jitclass/413/4

So an example would be:

```py
from numba import njit
from numba.typed import List
from numba.types import float64

a = njit()(lambda x,y: x-y)
b = njit()(lambda x,y: x+y)
c = njit()(lambda x,y: x/y)

function_type = float64(float64, float64).as_type()

funcs = List.empty_list(function_type)
funcs.append(a)
funcs.append(b)
funcs.append(c)

@njit
def switch(i, funcs, *args):
    return funcs[i](*args)

switch(2, funcs, 1, 2)
# 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, the signatures of my functions weren't the same.